# Xcode 4.5 ios6 multiple lines with text in a button

Tags: button, text, ios6, storyboard, xcode4.5

When I'm make a button on the screen in the storyboard and have more text in it than the buttons width. The text just keep on going on a straight line past the buttons end. When this happens I want to have a line break so I can have the text on two lines, but I can't figure out how to get two lines of text in a button in the storyboard..

Any ideas how I can get this done in the storyboard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set Line Break to "Word Wrap":

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should have figured it out myself, but sometimes I get so confused.. Thank you again, it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame of the button whatever you want by the code and set Line break to "Word Wrap".
Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not only should you "Word Wrap" the text but, you should also use the auto layout debugging tool and select the "add missing constraints."